# how to specific matplotlib color in a 2-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a gas map in type of numpy array that has value of (-1,unexplored area),(100,obstacle/wall) and (range of 20.0 until 30.0, gas concentration reading) like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkHuz.png)

but when I display it using matplotlib i cannot specific the  different color for wall(black), unexplored area(grey), and gas concentration (red contour)

the figure display by the matplotlib is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzq8v.png)

this is the program that i use to display in matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib


df = pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Japan Data/291,194/a 291,194 (11).xlsx")
array = df.to_numpy() 
x =range(0,400)
y = range(0,399)
plt.contourf(x,y,array,cmap="Reds_r")
plt.colorbar(label= "Gas concentration")
```

`

how i can display the gas map using matplotlib as the first figure?

Comment: This is likely caused because you're using the colormap `Reds_r`. It doesn't follow specifically what you want to do. I'm only guessing because I don't have your data, but I think your outside regions, wall, unexplored and etc have all different numeric values. If you map these values to a color using https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html, you'll likely get a plot you're satisfied with.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tsaVXAiHWcDqppzjigGsyDL4LQ2hwvNA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108848424986805891641&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: this is the example of data that i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that my comment sounded simplistic. I had more trouble following it that I should have, and I apologize.

Anyway, I was having problems getting the colormaps to accept the discrete values -1 and 100. I could get it to map between 20 and 30 well, but not those edge cases. I ended up doing a brute-force method that worked, but is much less elegant. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable might provide a better way. What I did was translate your 2D array of values into a 3D array of RGBA values, then plot it with imshow. Here's the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('./kernel.xlsx', header=None)
array = df.to_numpy()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = range(0, 400)
y = range(0, 400)
gas_data = array[(array > -1) & (array < 100)]
gas_min = gas_data.min()
gas_max = gas_data.max()

rows, cols = array.shape
arr3d = np.zeros((rows, cols, 4))
norm = Normalize(vmin=gas_min, vmax=gas_max)

for row_i in range(rows):
    for col_j in range(cols):
        val = array[row_i, col_j]
        if val == -1: # Unexplored
            color = (1, 1, 1, 1) # white
        elif val == 100: # Wall
            color = (0, 0, 0, 1) # black
        else:
            color = plt.cm.Reds_r(norm(val))
        arr3d[row_i, col_j, :] = color
    # print(row_i+1, " of ", rows)
ax.imshow(np.flipud(arr3d))
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: wow..you such a wonderful programmer..This is what i need..thank you so much for helping me :)